# Hand Jitter Problem

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am currently developing algorithm using openCV C++ for implementing laser as a mouse.Currently am having an issue of hand jitters.(ie. The presenter's hand may shake unnecessarily which may cause pointer to move continuously.).Can anyone please tell me how to avoid this problem using openCV or is there any in build function available to overcome this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having an OpenCV solution for you, but what about the following approachs:

**#1**

1. Assume that the jitter is Gaussian and calculate the mean and variance of the laser point for a certain number of frames (this number is something that you should estimate or measure in an experiment)
2. Keep the mouse cursor at the mean position.
3. Update the position of the mouse cursor only if the mean position has changed more than one standard deviation.

**#2**

Calculate the mean position of the laser point for a certain number of frames (this number is something that you should estimate or measure in an experiment). This is the same as a sliding average position of the laser point. Use this mean position as the cursor position.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution.Will work on it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle the hand jitter problem in your laser-as-mouse project using OpenCV, you might want to consider implementing a noise reduction algorithm or some form of smoothing to your pointer movements. This can help to stabilize the pointer position by reducing the influence of small, rapid, and unintentional movements.

Here are a few methods you could try:

1. **Averaging**: Keep track of the last N positions of the pointer, and set the current position to be the average of these positions. This is a simple but potentially effective way of reducing jitter.
2. **Low-pass filter**: Use a low-pass filter (LPF) to smooth the pointer's movement. A LPF allows signals with a frequency lower than a certain cutoff frequency to pass through and attenuates signals with frequencies higher than the cutoff frequency. Jitter, being a high frequency signal, would be reduced.

Here's a simple example of how you might apply a LPF:

```cpp
// alpha is a value between 0 and 1
double alpha = 0.5; 
Point smoothedPoint;

void smooth(Point newPoint) {
  smoothedPoint.x = alpha * newPoint.x + (1 - alpha) * smoothedPoint.x;
  smoothedPoint.y = alpha * newPoint.y + (1 - alpha) * smoothedPoint.y;
}
```

In this code, `alpha` is the degree of smoothing. The smaller the value, the greater the degree of smoothing (and thus the greater the delay in response to movement).

3. **Median Filter**: You could also try using a median filter, which can be particularly effective at removing 'spike' noise which could be causing the jitter.

Remember, OpenCV is a very powerful library, but there isn't a pre-made function for everything. You might have to customize your solution to the specific characteristics of your application.

I hope this helps, and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

I would model the trajectory based some previous points. Then I would estimate the new points based on a Kalman filter.